# Having a problem with installing the Azure IoT SDK for C

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am following the MS docs quickstart on creating an IoT Plug and Play device for Windows i.e [Quickstart: Use a device capability model to create an IoT Plug and Play Preview device (Windows)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-pnp/quickstart-create-pnp-device-windows) and I'm having issues preparing the development environment.

When I get to installing the SDK with vcpkg (step 2 in preparing the dev environment section) running this command gives me an error:

```
.\vcpkg.exe install azure-iot-sdk-c[public-preview,use_prov_client]
```

[image]

It doesn't seem to take the **use_prov_client** flag. If I remove that flag the SDK installs correctly but then the rest of the quickstart doesn't compile as it apparently needs the client portions of the SDK installed.

Can anyone help with this? I'm not sure why it won't take that flag.

Thanks.

Comment: Yup, I too see the issue, have you run the command to check the available list 'vckpg search' and check if you see the  use_prov_client listed ?

Comment: I have submitted the Bug on the official GitHub page, [Having a problem with vckpg: installing the Azure IoT SDK for C](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/12180).The team will soon help us. You can also follow the link to track this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the workaround...

Go to the Folder : C:\Users\satish\vcpkg\ports\azure-iot-sdk-c

1. Edit the **CONTROL** file in any file editor, update use_prov_client as **use-prov-client**

[image]

2. Edit the **portfile.cmake** file : update use_prov_client as **use-prov-client**

[image]

3. run

> .\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat

4. run

> .\vcpkg.exe install azure-iot-sdk-c[public-preview,use-prov-client]

Finally...

[image]

Please let us know if you need further help.